# Activating one object disables another object's transparency

Tags: shaders, transparency, displacement

I have a plane with a displacement modifier and assigned different colors to the z-values by a color ramp. I then animated it that it extends from individual points to the whole plane by keyframing the color ramp, also with alpha values. It works absolutely fine, unless I activate another plane lying underneath with a solid color. When I check visibility in Viewport or Render, the first (smaller) mesh looses its transparency.
I've already tried to change the Principled BSDF to diffuse or use a transparency shader, but that didn't solve the problem. Is it more likely a problem with the shaders, or with general Blender settings?
Thanks for any help.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, are your planes on the same z-value ?

Comment: No, the larger plane without transparency is on a lower z-value.

Comment: This probblem occurs in both render engine (Cycles & Eevee)?

Comment: Yes, I was working in cycles but switching to eevee didn't solve it either.